# Returning an object from dequeue function?

Tags: c++, linked-list, queue

I am trying to get a linked-list class-based queue that holds objects of type "Student", but I've been trying for two days to get this thing to work. Now I am seeing errors of exceptions at the copy constructor of the "Student" class and the return of the dequeue function, and am at a complete loss since I don't even know what that means.

My main issue, from what I can tell, is when I try to assign the return of the dequeue to an object, there is an issue with the fact that I'm using the standard = operator and not a custom operator= for the class. Then again, I am relatively new to classes so I don't know if this is actually the issue.

This is the main code that uses all my files:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string> 
#include "Student.h"
#include "Queue.h"

int main(void)
{
    char TempFName[15], TempSName[20];
    long Tid_num;
    int Tage;
    float Tgpa;
    Student Student1, StudentA;
    queue q1;
    int no, temp;

    ifstream ip("input.txt");
    // modify for your location
    ip >> no;       /* read in the number of Students */
    for (temp = 0; temp < no; temp++)
    {
        /* read in the Student data in file format */
        ip >> TempFName;
        Student1.assignFName(TempFName);
        ip >> TempSName;
        Student1.assignSName(TempSName);
        ip >> Tid_num;
        Student1.assignId(Tid_num);
        ip >> Tage;
        Student1.assignAge(Tage);
        ip >> Tgpa;
        Student1.assignGpa(Tgpa);
        q1.enqueue(Student1);
    }
    ip.close();
    queue q2(q1);
    q2.enqueue(StudentA);   
    q1.enqueue(StudentA);
    cout << "details for queue 2 are as follows" << endl;
    for (temp = 0; temp < no + 1; temp++)
    {
        Student1 = q2.dequeue();
        Student1.print();
    }
    cout << "There are " << Student1.getNum() << " Student objects in existence";

    return 0;
}
```

My files are:

Student.cpp:

```
#include <iostream> // need for cout, etc
#include "Student.h"

using namespace std;




Student::Student(const Student& s)
{
    firstname = s.firstname;
    surname = s.surname;
    id_num = s.id_num;
    age = s.age;
    gpa = s.gpa;
    count++;
}
Student::~Student() { count--; }

void Student::assignFName(string tempFName)
{
    firstname = tempFName;
}

void Student::assignSName(string tempSName) { surname = tempSName; }
void Student::assignId(long Tid_num) { id_num = Tid_num; }
void Student::assignAge(int Tage) { age = Tage; }
void Student::assignGpa(float Tgpa) { gpa = Tgpa; }

string Student::getSName() { return surname; }
long Student::getId_num() { return id_num; }
int Student::getAge() { return age; }
float Student::getGpa() { return gpa; }
int Student::getNum() { return count; }

void Student::print() const
{

    cout << firstname << " " << surname << " " << id_num << " " << age << " ";
    cout << gpa << endl; // could do on same line, but do on next line just so can see that can be multiple lines, etc
}

int Student::count = 0;
```

Student.h:

```
#pragma once
//Module.h
#ifndef STD_H
#define STD_H

#include <string>
using namespace std;



class Student
{

public:
    // just include one constructor definition  here to show how it is written if do inline 
    Student(string fn = "nofirstname", string sn = "nosurname", long i = 0000, int a = 0, float s = 0)
        :firstname(fn), surname(sn), id_num(i), age(a), gpa(s) {

        count++;
    }

    Student(const Student& s);
    ~Student();

    void assignFName(string tempFName);
    void assignSName(string tempSName);
    void assignId(long Tid_num);
    void assignAge(int Tage);
    void assignGpa(float Tgpa);
    string getFName() { return firstname; } // just include one method here to show how it is written if do inline 
    string getSName();
    long getId_num();
    int getAge();
    float getGpa();
    void print() const;
    static int getNum();



private:
    string firstname, surname;
    long id_num;
    int age;
    float gpa;
    static int count;
};



#endif
```

queue.cpp:

```
#include "Queue.h"
#include "Student.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

void queue::enqueue(Student value) {
    QueueNode* temp = new QueueNode(value);     //allocating memory for the newly created node, with a value passed into it
    if (tail == NULL) {         //If there is no tail (i.e. only 1 block in the queue)...
        head = tail = temp;     //The tail and head are now the one block
        return;                 //
    }                           //
    tail->next = temp;          //The next address of the tail is made to equal the temporary node
    tail = temp;                //The tail becomes the temporary node
    delete temp;
}

Student queue::dequeue() {
    Student a;
        if (head == tail) {//if only one node is there
            head = tail = NULL;
        } else {
            head = head->next;
        }
        if (head == NULL) {
            exit(1);
        }
        a = head->value;
        return a;
    

   //Student a;
   //QueueNode* temp = head;     //store the current head node of the queue
   //delete (temp);
   //if (head != NULL) {
   //    head = head->next;
   //
   //} else {
   //    tail = NULL;
   //    //return a;
   //}
   //a = head->value;
   //return a;
}

void queue::printQueue() {
    int count = 1;                                              //initiazling counter variable as 1 so that the counter does not start at 0
    while (head != NULL)                                        //while the are still blocks in the queue
    {
        //cout << "\n\tBlock number " << count << " pushed: " << ; //print the block that was just inserted and what position it is at
        head->value.print();
        head = head->next;                                                  //equate the node to the next address
        count++;                                                            //increment the counter
    }
}

queue::~queue() {
    head = tail = NULL;
}

queue::queue(const queue& q) {
    QueueNode* hold = q.head;
    QueueNode* temp, * oldtemp;
    if (hold == q.tail)
    {
        temp = new QueueNode;
        head = temp;
        tail = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        temp = new QueueNode;
        head = temp;
        while (hold != q.tail)
        {
            // get the value at the node looking at on queue 'r' list
            temp->value = hold->value;
            // move to the next entry on 'r' list
            hold = hold->next;
            oldtemp = temp;
            temp = new QueueNode;
            oldtemp->next = temp;
        }
        tail = temp;
    }
}

queue::queue() {
    head = tail = NULL;
}

//queue::sizeOfQueue() {                       //function to return the number of nodes in the queue
//                                                                //takes in the pointer to the queue so that the function knows which queu to get the size of
//    int size = 0;                                               //intialize size integer to be returned
//    while (node != NULL) {                                      //for as long as a NULL node is not reached
//        node = node->next;                                      //equate the node to the next address
//        size++;                                                 //increment the size integer
//    }                                                           //eventually the node will reach the end of the queue where the next address is NULL (because there are no other nodes)
//    return size;                                                //return the integer for the size
//}
```

queue.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "Student.h"
#include "Node.h"

class queue {
public:
    queue();
    queue(const queue& q);
    ~queue();
    void enqueue(Student value);
    Student dequeue();
    void printQueue();
private:
    QueueNode* head;
    QueueNode* tail;
};
```

Node.cpp:

```
#include "Queue.h"
#include "Node.h"
#include "Student.h"
#include <iostream>

QueueNode::QueueNode() {
    value = Student();
    next = NULL;
}

QueueNode::QueueNode(Student val) {
    value = val;
    next = NULL;
}

QueueNode::~QueueNode() {
    value.~Student();
    next = NULL;
}
```

Node.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "Student.h"

class QueueNode {

    friend void enqueue(Student value);
    friend void dequeue();
    friend void printQueue();

public: 
    QueueNode* next;                //PUBLIC VARIABLE
    Student value;
    QueueNode();
    QueueNode(Student val);
    ~QueueNode();
private:

};
```

The input file that gets the details for the "Student" objects that go in the queue:

```
3
joe bloggs 40001 24 2.1
mary doe 40002 19 3.9
john boyd 40003 18 1
```

Comment: Please try to explain your `queue::dequeue()` function to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: *Now I am seeing errors of exceptions at the copy constructor of the "Student" class* -- Your `Student` class does not require a user-defined copy constructor.  It also doesn't need to have a user-defined destructor.  All of the members variables of `Student` are safely copyable without "help" from the programmer.  All you're doing when you write a user-defined copy constructor is to prevent the compiler from invoking its own version, which in your case would be safe and efficient.  Thus there is no need to step in and risk bugs by writing code you don't need to write.

Comment: To follow up on my previous comment, your `dequeue` function either dereference a null pointer, or dereference the wrong pointer. And is leaking memory.

Comment: Oh and your `enqueue` function is wrong as well, as it could leave your list with invalid pointers.

Comment: Thank you, you are correct actually, now that I've looked at it properly and not with eyes of desperacy, my dequeue and enqueue functions are broken.

Comment: Have you able to fix the issue? If so, please consider putting an answer by yourself in this post so that others can get help from there.